# Synapse serverless data lake designer don't recognize partition format as a date time

Tags: azure-synapse

to improve a query performance, I have decided to partition a relatively Big table by a column date (l_shipdate).
I used synapse spark which was rather a good experience, here is the layout of the new table
[image]

now when I try to define a new table using Data Lake Designer, whatever datetime format I assign, I get an errors latter when running a Query either using SQL Serverless or Spark

[image]

my Question is what format should I use.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your issue is the colons in your time value are getting url encoded. Other than that your format is correct.